# Listen for a function to be called JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have the following functions that is called every 2 seconds to load some data. It registers the function [`do`] to do the stuff with the response. (the example is simplified).

```
function doRequest (){
    $.ajax({ url: 'www.google.com.pe', success: function (response) {do(response)} });
}

function do (text){
    var i = setInterval(doRequest, 2000);
}
```

I wonder if there is any way that I can create a function that is called every time the [`do`] function is called with out needing to add a call to the listener inside the do function. If there is any better way to do it with jQuery, like a plugin I'd appreciate the help.

[Edit] The idea is not whether it works or not. My question was about if I can add a custom listener to the "do" function which was already implemented. Something like `addActionListener("do", "after", doSomeThingElse)`,sSo I could do some thing else just after the do function has finished.

Comment: `2000` = 2 secs not 2 minutes. What you have in setInterval is milli seconds.. This is just a comment

Comment: Do not name your function `do`. `do` is a reserved word in Javascript.

Comment: And by the way, for `setInterval`'s arguments need to be flipped - the function comes first, then the milliseconds: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: Thanks, made the example on the fly, huge error there.

Comment: I think you are looking for the observer pattern in javascript: http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-observer-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep existing code as it is, you could wrap `do()` in another function which in turn calls `do()` and your new function (say `do_this_as_well()`).

See the example below (I renamed `do()` to `do_this()` to avoid confusion around the reserved keyword `do`). This works because global functions are nothing but variables with function objects in them. These variables can be overwritten, in this case with a new function that calls the old one:

```
function do_this(response) { ... }

(function()
{
    var previous=do_this;
    do_this=function(response) { previous(response); do_this_as_well(); }
})();
```

Comment: You are overwitting the first function and wraping the same old functionality in a new one with the Action I'd need to call; would it keep the reference from the ajax callback?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you're doing exactly, you say that your example is simplified. But if you pass a single response parameter, this parameter will be forwarded.

Comment: I understood that It will overwrite it, and the example (as it is there) will work calling the ´do_this´ function when ever the ajax request is successfull. It makes sence, specially since you added the why. did I got it right?

Answer (score 6):

First, your simplified version won't work, because you'd need to pass the `do` function instead of calling it.

```
function doRequest (){
    $.ajax({ url: 'www.google.com.pe', success: _do });
}
```

---

But it sounds like you're asking how to run some other code every time `do` is invoked.

If `do` is only invoked inside the `doRequest()` function, then just add your other code to an anonymous function that invokes `do` at the right time.

```
function doRequest (){
    $.ajax({ url: 'www.google.com.pe', success: function(response) {
          // Run your other code
          //   or invoke another function.
          _do(response);
    } });
}
```

If you want it to be more generalized, you can create a function decorator that returns a function which invokes `do` after some other code.

```
function doFactory(fn) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        _do.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

then make functions like this:

```
var doFoo = doFactory(function() {
    console.log("foo");
});
```

---

If your requirement is more specific of a pre-processing of `response`, you could rework it like this:

```
function doFactory(fn) {
    return function(response) {
        _do.call(this, fn.call(this, response));
    }
}
```

Then have the `fn` manipulate and return `response`.

```
var doFoo = doFactory(function(response) {
    return response + "foo";
});
```

Comment: Kind of trying to work with the same code, so my question was more about adding an "eventListener"

Comment: @jaxkodex: Regarding your edit, no you can't directly modify `do` *(at least without some hackish `.toString()` and `eval` tricks)* or bind some event to its invocation. But you *can* easily wrap `do` in another function that does some other work. There are several approaches to this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
success: do(response)
```

with

```
success: function(response) { do(response); do_this_as_well(); }
```

Comment: So, there is no way to add a listener to that already built in function?

Comment: I see. I suppose you could wrap do() in another function, which would work like a listener, but JavaScript does not provide natively what you want.

Comment: I guess the solution, then, would be to modify the success callback from the ajax request. Is there any way to do this in runtime ( I can't change the code)-  Thank's for the answer by the way.

Comment: Check out my other answer which replaces do() at runtime.